# Minesweeper program java x and y on 2d array are switched

Tags: java, user-interface, multidimensional-array

im creating a code for Minesweeper and trying to implement a GUI. But the problem is that when i run the code and play the game, the position i click on the board reveals the y,x coordinate of that location on the answer board rather than the x, y coordinate. Ive been trying to fix this but i cant see to figure it out.  i think it maybe is the way i create the board, but i tried everything i could think of.

```
class Board{

public MsGUI gui;

private static char[][] userBoard;
private static char[][] solutionBoard;
private static int boundSize = 5;

public Board(){
 userBoard = new char[][]   {{'-','-','-','-','-'},
                              {'-','-','-','-','-'},
                              {'-','-','-','-','-'},
                              {'-','-','-','-','-'},
                              {'-','-','-','-','-'}};  

 solutionBoard = new char[][] {{'0','2','B','2','0'},
                {'0','3','B','3','0'},
                {'1','3','B','3','1'},
                {'B','1','3','B','2'},
                {'1','1','2','B','2'}};

 return;
    }    

private static void printBoard(char[][] board){      
     for (int x = 0; x < boundSize; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < boundSize; y++){
            System.out.print(" " + Character.toString(board[x][y]));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }        

    System.out.println("");
}

public void flagCell(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate){
    userBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] = 'F';


}

public boolean isFlagged(int xCoordinate,int yCoordinate){

if(userBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] == 'F'){

return true;

}

else{

return false;

}
}

public int getHeight() {

return userBoard.length;

}

public int getWidth(){

return userBoard[0].length;
}

public char getValue(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate) {

return userBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate];

}
private static boolean checkIfAlreadyMarked(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)
{
    boolean marked = false;

    if (Character.toString(userBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate]).equals("-") == false)
    {
        marked = true;
    }

    return marked;
}


public void revealCell(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate){

    int count = 0;

for(int i = 0;i < userBoard.length;i++){

    for(int J = 0;J < userBoard[i].length;J++){

        if(userBoard[i][J] != '-'){
        count = count + 1;
    }
}

if(count == 19){

gui.win("you won");

return;

}

}

    if(solutionBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] == 'B'){
        userBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] = solutionBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate];
        gui.lose("You lost. Better luck next time!");
        return;
    }   
    if(solutionBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] != '0'){
        userBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] = solutionBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate];
    }else{

        userBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] = solutionBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate];

        for(int i = 1; i > -2; i--){

            if(xCoordinate-i >= solutionBoard.length || xCoordinate-i < 0)
                continue;

            for(int z = 1; z > -2; z--){

                if(yCoordinate-z >= solutionBoard[xCoordinate].length || yCoordinate-z < 0)
                    continue;


                else if(userBoard[xCoordinate-i][yCoordinate-z] == 'F' || userBoard[xCoordinate-i][yCoordinate-z] != '-')
                    continue;

                else{
                    revealCell(xCoordinate-i, yCoordinate-z);
                }
            }
        }   
    }





}



  public void unflagCell(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate){

userBoard[xCoordinate][yCoordinate]='-';

}
public static void main(String[] args){
Board b = new Board();
b.gui = new MsGUI(b);
b.gui.setVisible(true);


}
}
```

Comment: Can't you just swap them then?

Comment: yeah i tried to replace the xCoordinate with the yCoordinate, but it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

The way you are initializing the solutionBoard is not what you expect it to be. 
If you get solutionBoard[0], you're not accessing the first column(which would be consistent with what I think is your understanding), but the first row(first item of the two-dimensional array): {'0','2','B','2','0'}

So if you want to have x for a row index and y for a column index and still keep this "readable" initialization, you'll have to swap the indices whenever you access the array.
But this will only help you with one problem - human readable array assignment in the beginning, but I think you'll regret this decision in the future.

EDIT: 
You can have the array initialized as you want and still use readable format like this:

```
String readableBoard =
            "0 2 B 2 0;" +
            "0 3 B 3 0;" +
            "1 3 B 3 1;" +
            "B 1 B B 2;" +
            "1 1 2 B 2";
char[][] board = initBoard(readableBoard);

....

private char[][] initBoard(String readableBoard){
    char[][] board = new char[5][5];
    String[] rows = readableBoard.split(";");
    String[] fields = null;
    for (int y = 0; y<rows.length;y++){
        fields = rows[y].split(" ");
        for (int x = 0; x<fields.length; x++){
            board[x][y]=fields[x].charAt(0);
        }
    }
    return board;
}
```

Now when you call

```
board[2][0]
```

You'll get 'B'

Comment: yes, at this point, soutionBoard[0] accesses the first column instead of the first row.

Comment: Ok. And what do you want the x to be? "Horizontal" index?

Comment: ok, so if i were to get rid of the "readable" initialization of the solutionBoard, how would that go about fixing the problem with accessing the right column and row?

Comment: and yes, i meant for x to be the horizontal axis

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your nested for loops, you're printing off the columns instead of what I assume to be the desired rows. Try switching your for loops to iterate over y, then x.

```
   for (int y = 0; y < boundSize; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < boundSize; x++){
        System.out.print(" " + Character.toString(board[x][y]));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}        

System.out.println("");
```

Comment: yeah i tried switching the loops to iterate over y first then x and it didnt work